# R reshape dataframe

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)

d1 <- data_frame(
type = c("type1", "type2", "all"),
 `2018` = c(2, 3, 5),
 `2019` = c(4, 8, 12),
 `2020` = c(2, 6, 8))
```

I want to plot the data using ggplot but I want it to be in long format to do so. I would like the data to look like this:

```
d2 <- data_frame(
  type = c("type1", "type2", "all", "type1", "type2", "all", "type1", 
"type2", "all"),
  Year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", 
"2020" ),
  Value = c(2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 12, 2, 6, 8))
```

I have looked at the reshape library, particularly the melt function but I can't quite get what I want. This article https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/ is quite useful as well, but again the shape of the data that I'm starting with is different, so it doesn't answer my question.

Thanks

Comment: check with melt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gather() from `tidyr`

```
d1 <- d1 %>%
  gather(key=year,value=value,2:4)
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  type  year  value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 type1 2018      2
2 type2 2018      3
3 all   2018      5
4 type1 2019      4
5 type2 2019      8
6 all   2019     12
7 type1 2020      2
8 type2 2020      6
9 all   2020      8
```

Comment: You're welcome! You might also want to convert the year column to numeric after you've done this.